# Use output of one function as input of another function

Tags: python, while-loop, beautifulsoup

so I want to check a website to update me whenever there's a new item posted.  They don't update often so I'm fairly certain when they do update it will be the item of interest.  I want to achieve this by choosing a "starting number" and count the number of links on the page then compare that number to the number of links every 10 minutes, until the number of links are greater than the starting number.

First I run this to get the "starting number" of links:

```
links=[]
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
start_num = len(links)
```

Then compare that number to the number of links right now and every 5 seconds:

```
notify=True
while notify:
    try: 
        page = urllib.request.urlopen('web/site/url')
        soup = bs(page, "lxml")  

        links=[]
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            links.append(link.get('href'))

        if len(links) > start_num:
            message = client.messages.create(to="", from_="",body="") 
            print('notified')
            notify=False
        else:
            print('keep going')
            time.sleep(60*5)

    except:
        print("Going to sleep")
        time.sleep(60*10)
```

How can I combine all this into 1 function where I run can store the starting number of links without overwriting it every time I check it against the current number of links?

Comment: if you want to retain the state in a function, you should consider use class .

Answer (score 0):

you can do it at least two ways: decorators and generators

Decorators:

```
def hang_on(func):

    # soup should be in a visible scope
    def count_links():
        # refresh page?
        return len(soup.findAll('a'))

    start_num = count_links()

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                new_links = count_links()
                if  new_links > start_num:
                    start_num = new_links
                    return fund(*args, **kwargs)
                print('keep going')
                time.sleep(60*5)            
            except:
                print("Going to sleep")
                time.sleep(60*10)         

    return wrapper

@hang_on    
def notify():
    message = client.messages.create(to="", from_="",body="") 
    print('notified')

# somewhere in your code, simply:
notify()
```

Generators:

```
def gen_example(soup):

    # initialize soup (perhaps from url)

    # soup should be in a visible scope
    def count_links():
        # refresh page?
        return len(soup.findAll('a'))

    start_num = count_links()

    while True:
        try:
            new_links = count_links()
            if  new_links > start_num:
                start_num = new_links
                message = client.messages.create(to="", from_="",body="") 
                print('notified')
                yield True  # this is what makes this func a generator

            print('keep going')
            time.sleep(60*5)            
        except:
            print("Going to sleep")
            time.sleep(60*10)       

# somewhere in your code:
gen = gen_example(soup)  # initialize

gen.next()  # will wait and notify

# coming soon
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it as a class, because this code is quite readable and easy to support. Enjoy:

```
class Notifier:
    url = 'web/site/url'
    timeout = 60 * 10

    def __links_count(self):
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        soup = bs(page, "lxml")

        links=[]
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            links.append(link.get('href'))

        return len(links)

    def __notify(self):
        client.messages.create(to="", from_="", body="")
        print('notified')

    def run(self):
        current_count = self.__links_count()

        while True:
            try:
                new_count = self.__links_count()

                if new_count > current_count:
                    self.__notify()
                    break

                sleep(self.timeout)

            except:
                print('Keep going')
                sleep(self.timeout)

notifier = Norifier()
notifier.run()
```

Comment: so the self used as arguments within the functions (self.url, self.timeout) always refer to variables not defined in any of the methods defined in the class?